# How to resize JComponent forcefully in a null layout?

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to resize a panel in a container panel where the container panel's layout is set to null.

I am setting the location and changing the size like this:

```
panelCapture.setLocation(
        scale.scale(((capture.getTotalBounds().width + 500)  / 2) - (capture.getTotalBounds().width  / 2)),
        scale.scale(((capture.getTotalBounds().height + 500) / 2) - (capture.getTotalBounds().height / 2))
);

Dimension pcSize    = panelCapture.getSize();
Dimension pcNewSize = new Dimension(scale.scale(pcSize.width), scale.scale(pcSize.height));

panelCapture.setSize(pcNewSize);
panelCapture.setPreferredSize(pcNewSize);
```

The scaling multiplies it by my current scale which is 1.0f, 1.1f, etc.

Changing the position seems to work but changing the size does not.

Comment: `panel's layout is set to null` Any particular reason you are using a `null` layout?

Comment: Because there is no other way to position a panel in this way. I am creating a screenshot program. There is a container panel that is the width of your monitor plus padding. Then inside of that container panel there is a panel that is the exact size of your monitor. Inside of that panel the image selection of the screenshot is painted at the coordinates it was at on the screen. Then the user can resize the image inside of that panel. When I zoom in it needs to scale the panel.

Comment: Can you include a SSCCE?  It's not especially clear what capture & scale are.

Comment: They are non-relevant. It could just as easily say panelCapture.setLocation(5, 5). I am sorry for the confusion. The problem is that I am able to move the panel using setLocation, but am unable to re-size the panel using setSize or setPreferredSize.

Comment: No worries.  The SSCCE just makes it easier for someone else to reproduce the problem and test the solution so they don't have to write it from scratch.

Comment: Well, I think my detail complicates the problem. I was just wondering how to re-size Swing components after they were created, basically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using setLocation and setSize, try [setBounds(...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setBounds(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) or [setPreferredSize(...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setPreferredSize(java.awt.Dimension)).  You may also need a call to repaint() after that.  You may want to refer to the tutorial on using absolute/null layout [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html).

Here's a sample I wrote to change the size of a JPanel inside another JPanel which has a null layout (using only setBounds).

```
public class Capture
{
    JPanel capture;
    JPanel panelCapture;
    JTextField scaleField;
    JButton changeScale;

    static final int PARENT_WIDTH = 800;
    static final int PARENT_HEIGHT = 600;

    static final int CHILD_WIDTH = 100;
    static final int CHILD_HEIGHT = 100;

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        Capture c = new Capture();
        c.doStuff();
    }

    public void doStuff()
    {
        capture = new JPanel();
        capture.setLayout(null);
        capture.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(PARENT_WIDTH, PARENT_HEIGHT));

        scaleField = new JTextField();
        scaleField.setBounds(100, 550, 200, 25);
        capture.add(scaleField);

        changeScale = new JButton("Scale");
        changeScale.setBounds(325, 550, 100, 25);
        changeScale.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                panelCapture.setBounds(getBounds(CHILD_WIDTH * Float.parseFloat(scaleField.getText()), CHILD_HEIGHT * Float.parseFloat(scaleField.getText())));
            }
        });
        capture.add(changeScale);

        panelCapture = new JPanel();
        panelCapture.setBackground(Color.blue);
        panelCapture.setBounds(getBounds(CHILD_WIDTH, CHILD_HEIGHT));
        capture.add(panelCapture);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setContentPane(capture);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private Rectangle getBounds(float width, float height)
    {
        int left = (int) (PARENT_WIDTH - width) / 2;
        int top = (int) (PARENT_HEIGHT - height) / 2;
        return new Rectangle(left, top, (int) width, (int) height);
    }
}
```

Comment: This did not change its behavior. I will look more into the issue tomorrow, but thanks for your help.

Comment: You're welcome for the help.  setBounds works for me, so something else must be missing from your code.  If you want to post a short compilable sample of your code that reproduces the problem, I'd be happy to look at it...

Comment: I did some tests in creating a new window with two more general panels and attempted to resize them from an outside source, and it worked correctly. For this reason I will mark your answer as correct to help future users. I am sorry for the confusion.

Comment: And my code is a fairly large program, so I could probably not produce a working version of this without showing all of the part. If you email me at connorelsea@gmail.com, I can show you my Github. It is an open source project and I always love having new contributors or helpers of any kind. Thank you.